# Why Restful WCF Services is preffered for Mobile Applications?

Tags: wcf, rest

Why Restful WCF Services is preffered for Mobile Applications? Can we use normal WCF to communicate?

Answer (score 1):

Mobile apps or any client can call the RESTful services directly and easily without the SOAP protocol and RESTful services return json data by default, so its easily usable on the client side. Its really difficult and cumbersome to call WCF service from mobile and other client application.

Have a look at the links below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj823172(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/JI2X050413-Difference-between-WCF-and-Web-API-and-WCF-REST-and-Web-Service.html